# Error when pushing to master

Tags: git

When I am trying to push my changes to the master I am getting an error saying,

```
fatal: remote error: Insufficient permissions
You do not have permissions to push to the repository <my repo name> in the project <project name>
```

My git repo is in **Atalassian STASH**

Comment: So do you have the permissions to push?

Comment: This directly means you may not be added as a contributor. Try contacting the owner. If you are the owner, are you using ssh or https protocol? In case of former, make sure the public key is added.

Comment: I got here from google having a similar error with a BitBucket repo. Issue was, the SSH key in BitBucket was missing after switching accounts. Could not be added because the old account (which was locked) still had it configured. So I used HTTPS access instead of SSH for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition of the possible authentication issue (wrong username/password for https access, or wrong/unknown public key sor ssh access), check the branch permissions.
See "[Using branch permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+branch+permissions)".

As specified in [this thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/115440/branch-level-permissions):

> branch permissions doesn't elevate the project level permissions. It is more of a restriction.
>   When you push changes to a repository:
>
> - first the project level permission is checked. This is the same as it was in Stash 1.x meaning the user must be a contributor (have write access) to the project in order for their push to proceed.
> - Stash then checks the branch permissions for each branch which is being updated.
>
>   - If a restriction exists and the user doesn't have permission the push is rejected.
>   - If there is no restriction or they have permission the push is successful.